# Making LineageOS even more lightweight

Tags: battery-life, lineageos, samsung-galaxy-s-5-mini

> How can I minimize the power footprint of my LOS?

My device is rooted and I have Termux. There I can run

```
$ su
# htop
```

and see that the device is running 83 processes (!).

These are the processes ordered by RAM-consumption:

```
  1  [||||                                                    5.6%]   Tasks: 83; 1 running
  2  [|||||||||                                              13.6%]   Load average: 2.92 2.41 2.25
  3  [|||||                                                   7.1%]   Uptime: 08:41:45
  4  [||                                                      1.2%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||473M/1.23G]
  Swp[                                                    0K/1024M]

VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
349M  213M  182M S  6.1 17.0 10:40.71 system_server
942M   98M 64496 S  0.0  7.8  2:07.61 com.android.systemui
898M 73096 53764 S  0.0  5.7  0:12.71 com.android.launcher3
869M 70724 48804 S  7.9  5.5  0:28.07 com.termux
001M 69448 59892 S  0.0  5.4  0:04.49 zygote
850M 66664 49636 S  0.0  5.2  0:06.64 com.android.inputmethod.latin
858M 58840 45960 S  0.0  4.6  0:04.01 com.android.phone
841M 58288 43200 S  0.0  4.5  0:02.12 com.topjohnwu.magisk
824M 53216 41948 S  0.0  4.1  0:02.28 com.joshsera
828M 51044 38292 S  0.0  4.0  0:29.72 android.process.media
833M 49820 37400 S  0.6  3.9  4:57.86 com.android.nfc
827M 45232 35236 S  0.0  3.5  0:00.38 com.android.deskclock
824M 42824 33144 S  0.0  3.3  0:00.29 com.android.calendar
827M 42032 32384 S  0.0  3.3  0:00.30 org.lineageos.lineageparts
824M 41924 32244 S  0.0  3.3  0:00.25 com.android.traceur
820M 41364 31636 S  0.0  3.2  0:00.40 com.android.settings.intelligence
824M 40452 30620 S  0.0  3.1  0:00.24 org.lineageos.audiofx
822M 39488 29944 S  0.0  3.1  0:00.26 org.lineageos.lockclock
818M 38960 29456 S  0.0  3.0  0:00.21 com.android.keychain
820M 38836 29092 S  0.0  3.0  0:00.21 com.android.se
817M 38252 28512 S  0.0  3.0  0:00.19 com.validity.fingerprint
005M 29012 19480 S  0.0  2.3  0:00.14 webview_zygote
9248 12664  9816 S  0.0  1.0  0:00.97 /system/bin/gpsd -c /system/etc/gps.xml
9304 12476  8460 S  3.6  1.0  2:08.56 /system/bin/surfaceflinger
1136 12120  9208 S  0.0  0.9  0:01.16 /system/bin/audioserver
6084 10360  8172 S  0.0  0.8  0:00.78 /system/bin/mediaserver
1004  9964  5780 S  0.0  0.8  0:00.70 /vendor/bin/hw/rild
4364  8812  5732 S  0.0  0.7  0:01.09 media.codec hw/android.hardware.media.omx@1.0-service
8556  8444  6200 S  0.0  0.7  0:00.50 media.extractor aextractor
0856  6708  4884 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.37 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-service.kminilte
8504  6040  4656 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.27 /system/bin/drmserver
8300  6004  4656 S  0.0  0.5  0:00.26 media.metrics diametrics
6864  4288  1340 S  0.0  0.3  0:36.68 /system/bin/logd
2432  4028  3180 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.15 /system/bin/keystore /data/misc/keystore
1644  4016  3244 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.10 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.drm@1.0-service
5596  3920  2680 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.44 /system/bin/vold --blkid_context=u:r:blkid:s0 --blkid_untrusted_context=u:r:blkid_untrusted:s0 --fsck_c
6320  3476  2628 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.59 /system/bin/netd
8008  3456  2740 S  0.0  0.3  0:01.03 /system/bin/vcsFPService
9616  3444  2792 S  0.0  0.3  0:01.14 /vendor/bin/hw/hostapd
2012  3400  2616 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.64 /system/bin/statsd
9484  3356  2588 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.65 /system/bin/hwservicemanager
9568  3324  2684 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.64 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service
6512  3312  2604 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.44 /system/bin/gatekeeperd /data/misc/gatekeeper
1808  3236  2620 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.08 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.gnss@1.0-service
5320  3132  2068 S  0.0  0.2  0:01.60 /system/bin/installd
2796  3112  2240 S  0.0  0.2  0:15.73 /system/bin/storaged
0096  3048  2364 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.08 /system/bin/mediadrmserver
8368  3028  2392 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.07 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.keymaster@3.0-service
9284  2964  2296 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.07 /system/bin/wificond
1672  2856  2116 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.07 magiskd
7572  2572  2024 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.06 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.cas@1.0-service
0020  2568  1988 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.06 /system/bin/incidentd
8308  2472  1936 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.06 /system/bin/thermalserviced
7204  2412  1896 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.05 /vendor/bin/hw/vendor.lineage.touch@1.0-service.samsung
6848  2408  1716 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.09 /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash -l
5856  2404  1200 S  0.0  0.2  0:03.80 /system/bin/dnsmasq --keep-in-foreground --no-resolv --no-poll --dhcp-authoritative --dhcp-option-force
7012  2376  1900 S  0.0  0.2  0:06.52 /system/bin/healthd
7228  2372  1864 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.05 /vendor/bin/hw/vendor.lineage.trust@1.0-service
7628  2312  1780 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.28 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@2.0-service
5780  2284  1332 R 10.3  0.2  1:13.78 htop
3028  2252  1324 S  0.0  0.2  0:02.97 /init
6880  2216  1720 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.04 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.memtrack@1.0-service
6876  2212  1716 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.04 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.ir@1.0-service
7568  2156  1648 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.06 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.configstore@1.1-service
9340  2136  1608 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.04 /system/bin/perfprofd --binder
8128  2064  1592 S  0.0  0.2  0:17.77 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.0-service
5916  2048  1192 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.12 /system/bin/ip6tables-restore --noflush -w -v
6744  2040  1584 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.04 /vendor/bin/hw/android.hardware.usb@1.0-service.basic
6688  2012  1572 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.11 /system/bin/hw/android.hidl.allocator@1.0-service
6416  1956  1404 S  0.0  0.2  0:01.37 /system/bin/servicemanager
5908  1912  1180 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.13 /system/bin/iptables-restore --noflush -w -v
1160  1720  1204 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.29 /system/bin/mcDriverDaemon -r /system/app/FFFFFFFF000000000000000000000001.drbin -r /system/app/mcRegis
5904  1692  1264 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 /vendor/bin/vndservicemanager /dev/vndbinder
4516  1580  1160 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.03 /system/bin/sh
4992  1544  1148 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.74 /system/bin/logcat -s Magisk
6348  1528  1160 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.41 /sbin/cbd -d -t ss222 -b m -m m
4884  1460  1120 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.10 /system/bin/lmkd
6668  1424  1072 S  0.6  0.1  0:02.13 /sbin/su
4680  1420  1076 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.03 /system/bin/tombstoned
4568  1164   760 S  0.0  0.1  0:01.13 /sbin/ueventd
3544   960   532 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 /init subcontext u:r:vendor_init:s0 9
3416   952   532 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /init subcontext u:r:vendor_init:s0 10
6936   436   316 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.04 /system/bin/adbd --root_seclabel=u:r:su:s0
```

I am using an old Galaxy S5 mini with LOS-GAPPS-free as a wireless touchpad. :)

It is nice, but I'd like the battery to last more than a day. (In flight-mode, with the screen off, and its used battery, the s5-mini achieves more than a week of battery life!! remember this is w/o GAPPs!)

How cool would it be to have an old device be your PC's touchpad and last over a week?!!

It all boils down to the processes that are active.

I certainly don't need 83 for a touchpad!

---

I have used Link2SD to deinstall and deactivate software and features in devices before to save machine-resources. It gives the option to Freeze as well, but many times, I have an annoying message that appears every 3 seconds about an app crashing. Like telephony. My smatphone-touchpad doesn't need telephony or gps services running. I would happily turn them off if the OS would stop annoying me about it being off and rebooting to recovery by itself!

---

I have come across this xda-post
https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unofficial-11-r-lineageos-18-1-for-z5c-suzuran.4205135/#post-84135891

and it seems to lead to the right direction.

> Does anyone here has experience with something like this? Which apps are the ones I can disable?

Comment: In standby the phone goes to proper sleep mode; when awake it doesn't and additionally boosts CPU on touch for responsiveness - these are kernel-level stuff that 1) can't be easily modified and 2) are for your own good (you don't want your touchpad to lag in use do you?)

Comment: true. still, those 83 processes can surely be reduces to (may be) 40, or even further.

Comment: for example the following could be (just guessing) removed: ```phone, nfc, calendar, traceur, audiofx, intelligence, keychain, fingerprint```. without those I'd stay below 1G of used RAM.